# OpenCL with HOG descriptor in Android

Tags: android, opencv, opencl

I am working on Android OpenCV HOG Descriptor. I need Android OpenCV HOG Descriptor with OpenCL. But android doesn't have OpenCL enabled Android OpenCV. Is there any functions in OpenCL for HOG Descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no HOG descriptor function in standard OpenCL, if that is what you are asking.  I would suggest examining the OpenCV code for calculating the HOG descriptors in OpenCL and see if you can directly use that code in your own app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me how can I use it android?